# Bullet doens't move. Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D, topdown, roguelike game but i got stuck when i tried to make a shooting system.
when i run it and press the arrow keys, the bullet spawns and points in the right direction. It juste doesn't move in any way.
This is my code and i hope someone can figure it out. Btw, everything is connected. The player and the bullet prefab.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Player))]
    public class PlayerShootController : ShootControllerBase
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private int _numberOfBombs;
        public int NumberofBombs
        {
            get { return _numberOfBombs; }
            set { _numberOfBombs = value; }
        }


        [SerializeField]
        private PlayerHeadController _headObject;
        public PlayerHeadController HeadObject
        {
            get { return _headObject; }
            set { _headObject = value; }
        }

        [SerializeField]
        private Bomb _bombPrefab;
        public Bomb BombPrefab
        {
            get { return _bombPrefab; }
            set { _bombPrefab = value; }
        }

        public bool IsShooting { get; private set; }
        private KeyCode _shootKey;
        private Vector2 _shootDirection;

        private Player _player;

        public override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();
            _player = GetComponent<Player>();
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            base.Update();

            if (IsShooting)
            {
                SetHeadDirection(_shootKey);
                return;
            }

            if (InputHelpers.IsAnyKey(KeyCode.UpArrow, KeyCode.DownArrow, KeyCode.LeftArrow, KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    _shootDirection = new Vector2(0, BulletSpeed);
                    _shootKey = KeyCode.UpArrow;
                }
                else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
                {
                    _shootDirection = new Vector2(0, -BulletSpeed);
                    _shootKey = KeyCode.DownArrow;
                }
                else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                {
                    _shootDirection = new Vector2(-BulletSpeed, 0);
                    _shootKey = KeyCode.LeftArrow;
                }
                else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
                {
                    _shootDirection = new Vector2(BulletSpeed, 0);
                    _shootKey = KeyCode.RightArrow;
                }
                StartCoroutine(Shoot());
            }
            if (NumberofBombs > 0 && InputHelpers.IsAnyKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift, KeyCode.RightShift, KeyCode.E))
            {
                var bomb = (Bomb) Instantiate(BombPrefab);
                bomb.transform.position = transform.position;
                NumberofBombs--;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator Shoot()
        {
            IsShooting = true;
            while (Input.GetKey(_shootKey))
            {
                var bullet = (Rigidbody2D)Instantiate(BulletPrefab);
                bullet.GetComponent<BulletScript>().Shooter = transform.gameObject;
                bullet.transform.position = transform.position;
                if (_shootDirection.y > 0)
                {
                    bullet.transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                }
                else if (_shootDirection.y < 0)
                {
                    bullet.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                }
                else if (_shootDirection.x > 0)
                {
                    TransformHelpers.FlipX(bullet.gameObject);
                }
                bullet.AddForce(_shootDirection);
                bullet.AddForce(_player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().GetPointVelocity(_player.transform.position) * 0.02f);

                if (ShootClips.Any())
                {
                    var clipToPlay = ShootClips[Random.Range(0, ShootClips.Count)];
                    clipToPlay.pitch = Random.Range(MinShootPitch, MaxShootPitch);
                    clipToPlay.Play();
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(ShootingSpeed);
            }
            IsShooting = false;

            //Reset head flipping
            if (_headObject.transform.localScale.x < 0)
            {
                TransformHelpers.FlipX(_headObject.gameObject);
            }
        }

        private void SetHeadDirection(KeyCode shootKey)
        {
            switch (shootKey)
            {
                case KeyCode.UpArrow:
                    _headObject.SetHeadDirection(PlayerHeadController.HeadDirection.Up);
                    break;
                case KeyCode.DownArrow:
                    _headObject.SetHeadDirection(PlayerHeadController.HeadDirection.Down);
                    break;
                case KeyCode.LeftArrow:
                    _headObject.SetHeadDirection(PlayerHeadController.HeadDirection.Left);
                    break;
                case KeyCode.RightArrow:
                    _headObject.SetHeadDirection(PlayerHeadController.HeadDirection.Right);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely once you have aimed your bullet you just add "forward" force....

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. but how do i add a forward force and where in the code exactly?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
bullet.AddForce(_shootDirection*moveSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
```

instead of this:

```
bullet.AddForce(_shootDirection);
 bullet.AddForce(_player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().GetPointVelocity(_player.transform.position) * 0.02f);
```

tweak the speed for desired result, and if you want the bullet to follow the player you will need to update the shoot direction every certain time with a couroutine

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment. but it doesnt change enything, the bullet doesnt move a single step. is there another option?

Comment: Ohh thats because you add the force only one time when the couroutine is called and if you are going to use time.Deltatime it needs to be inside update I personaly handle all movement in an update.... Anyhow.. You could find a way to call it several times... You can also just add enough force to it... And it will move.... Another solution it ro set a velocity to the rigidbody:   rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(x, y) ;